# PyQt v4.8.2 + Python 3...Icons only showing on dev-machine

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, pyqt

I wrote a little app with a gui to analyze xml files. I have 2 .py files where 1 is the GUI and the second handels the xml. 
My Problem is that the Icons i set and also a gif that i show using QMovie are not showing up on any machine but my development machine. 
The other machines do not have PyQt or Python installed. They are using my Installation-folder from Python that I've copied onto a network drive. The i just copied the python32.dll in the machines system32 folder and the app works...except for the icons.

That's how i set the icons and reference the gif:

```
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("grabb.ico"))
    --------other code---------
    self.movie = QMovie("load.gif", QByteArray(), self)
    self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
    self.movie.setSpeed(100)
    self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
    self.movie.start()
```

The file is in the same dir as the py so this should work. I've also tried absolute paths but that didn't give me any better results.

Now i have read on stack that this could be resolved by using the ressource-system. 
So i used the designer to create a ressource files and then compiled it using pyrcc4 into a .py (using the parameter for python 3). Now I'm reffering to the images like this:

```
     self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(":icon/grabber.ico"))
    --------other code---------
    self.movie = QMovie(":loader/load.gif", QByteArray(), self)
    self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
    self.movie.setSpeed(100)
    self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
    self.movie.start()
```

This again works fine on my machine but nowhere else.

Any ideas as to why only ma machine shows the icons ?
I'm not using py2exe or alike!

Comment: Okay problem solved. 
I'm now using cx_freeze to deploy it which I should have done in the first place.
Icons work and also the startup is faster because it doesn't have to load everything over that networkdrive.

cx_freeze all the way !

Answer (score 0):

I too came across the same situation.

One approach is to set the paths in qt.config file and place this in the location of your executable.

I tested this with Python 2.6, and its working fine without any issue.

You said that you have shared your python installation which has PyQt4 init.

Lets say you python share path is `\\somesystem\Python26`

Yo will find a qt.config file in `\\somesystem\Python26\PyQt4`. Take it and replace the below lines in qt.conf

```
[Paths]
Prefix = //somesystem/Python26/PyQt4
Binaries = //somesystem/Python26/PyQt4
```